# List and detail views error in Django using vies.py

Tags: python, django

I am using the following code in the views.py but i have an error with the Post. here is the code I use :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

- May I have some help to unserstand why the word "Post" in the following line is underline in red : posts = Post.published.all()

Note: I am using Visual Studio Code and Django 2.2

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is this a question related to the editor underlining the word `Post` or do you actually get a Django error in that line? If it's the latter, please write the error you're getting

Comment: Try hovering your mouse over `Post`, and you might get a tool tip saying what the problem is.

Comment: when trying to run the server : http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ I have the following error message : AttributeError at /blog/

type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not referencing the Post objects, also code of your Post model would be appreciated, but my guess is your code should be:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(published=True)
```

Assuming, that published is a booleanField

Comment: Hello Andrzej Dlugosz, thank you for the tips. The code you provide does not work but I follow it by simply replace "published by "objects. - So I replace posts = Post.published.all() by posts = Post.objects.all()